# Multiple asynchronous tasks with PromiseKit

Tags: asynchronous, swift3, swift4, promisekit

I have a form for a user to change his address. This form contains two checkboxes. The user can choose if he wants to save the form as billing address, shipping address or both. The both-part is giving me trouble. The PromiseKit documentation(Getting started) says about multiple asynchronous tasks:

> With completion handlers reacting to multiple asycnhronous operations
>   is either slow or hard. Slow means doing it serially:
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```
>
> Promises are easier:
>
> ```
> firstly {
> when(fulfilled: operation1(), operation2()) }.then { result1, result2 in
> //… }
> ```
>
> when takes promises, waits for them to resolve and returns a promise
>   with the results.
>
> And of course, if any of them fail the chain calls the next catch,
>   like any promise chain.

In the FAQ part it gives another code example:

> ```
> let p1 = promise.then {
>    // branch A
> }
>
> let p2 = promise.then {
>     // branch B
> }
>
> when(fulfilled: p1, p2).catch { error in
>    //…
> }
> ```

So I tried to handle my code as follows:

```
var p1 = Promise()
var p2 = Promise()
if self.checkboxBilling.isChecked && self.checkboxShipping.isChecked{
    p1 = DbRequests.updateAddresses(userId: UserDefaultsManager.userId, name: name, line1: line1, line2: line2, postCode: postCode, city: city, addressType: .billing)
    p2 = DbRequests.updateAddresses(userId: UserDefaultsManager.userId, name: name, line1: line1, line2: line2, postCode: postCode, city: city, addressType: .shipping)
} else{
    if self.checkboxBilling.isChecked{
        p1 = Promise{fullfil, reject in
            fullfil(())
        }
        p2 = DbRequests.updateAddresses(userId: UserDefaultsManager.userId, name: name, line1: line1, line2: line2, postCode: postCode, city: city, addressType: .billing)
    }
    if self.checkboxShipping.isChecked{
        p1 = Promise{fullfil, reject in
            fullfil(())
        }
        p2 = DbRequests.updateAddresses(userId: UserDefaultsManager.userId, name: name, line1: line1, line2: line2, postCode: postCode, city: city, addressType: .shipping)
    }
}
when(fulfilled: p1, p2).then{ _ -> Void in
    print("success")
}.catch { error in
    print(error)
}
```

If only one of the boxes is ticked, everything seems to work fine. When I tick both boxes, it only works sometimes, though. Sometimes only one of the addresses is updated.

What am I missing here?

---

## EDIT 28 Nov 17:

Here is the DbRequests.updateAdresses(...) function:

```
static func updateAddresses(userId: Int, name: String, line1: String, line2: String, postCode: String, city: String, addressType: AddressIdentifier) -> Promise<Void>{
    return Promise{fulfill, reject in
        var typeNumber: Int
        switch addressType{
        case .billing:
            typeNumber = 1
        case .shipping:
            typeNumber = 2
        }
        let parameters: [String : Any] = ["user_id": userId, "name": name, "line1": line1, "line2": line2, "post_code": postCode, "city": city, "address_type_id": typeNumber]
        Alamofire.request(App.rootdir + "/nailapp/functions/addAddresses.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseData() { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                fulfill(())
            case .failure(let error):
                reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine something is wrong with your `DbRequests.updateAddresses` function. Can you provide its code?

Comment: @mxcl updated my question.

Comment: This looks fine. One possibility is that the request is being cancelled, though I don’t see how, so try `catch(withPolicy: .allErrors)`.